# log4j2-test.properties file pattern layout not being picked up by custom AbstractAppender

Tags: java, unit-testing, logging, log4j2

I'm writing a unit test that uses SLF4J as the API and Log4J2 as the logging implementation.
I have a custom `AbstractAppender` (not using the `LogEvent` as yet) but am trying to output the `LogEvent` message and formatted message first using `System.out` to ensure Im getting what I am expecting - which I am not in this case.

Im expecting to see `"---WCustomAppender---"` as the prefix to my output messages as per my properties file pattern but it seems the pattern is not being picked up into my appender.

**Is there something Im missing like a property etc?**

All code below:

test/resources/**log4j2-test.properties**

```
packages = learning.logging
appenders=WCustomAppender

rootLogger.level=ERROR
rootLogger.appenderRefs=WCustomAppender
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref=WCustomAppender

appender.WCustomAppender.name=WCustomAppender
appender.WCustomAppender.type=WCustomAppender
appender.WCustomAppender.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.WCustomAppender.layout.pattern=---WCustomAppender--- %m %n
```

test/learning/logging/**WCustomAppender**

```java
package learning.logging;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Core;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Layout;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginAttribute;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginElement;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginFactory;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Plugin(
        name = "WCustomAppender",
        category = Core.CATEGORY_NAME,
        elementType = Appender.ELEMENT_TYPE)
class WCustomAppender extends AbstractAppender {

  private static final List<LogEvent> LOG_EVENTS = new ArrayList<>();

  protected WCustomAppender(String name, Filter filter, Layout<? extends Serializable> layout, boolean ignoreExceptions, Property[] properties) {
    System.out.println("layout loaded in appender from constructor: " + layout);
    super(name, filter, layout, ignoreExceptions, properties);
  }

  @PluginFactory
  public static WCustomAppender createAppender(
          @PluginAttribute("name") String name,
          @PluginElement("Filter") Filter filter,
          @PluginElement("Layout") Layout<? extends Serializable> layout) {
    return new WCustomAppender(name, filter, layout, false, Property.EMPTY_ARRAY);
  }

  public List<LogEvent> getLogEvents() {
    return LOG_EVENTS;
  }

  @Override
  public void append(LogEvent event) {
    System.out.println("message: " + event.getMessage());
    System.out.println("message (formatted): " + event.getMessage().getFormattedMessage());
    LOG_EVENTS.add(event);
  }
}
```

test/learning/logging/**LogTester**

```java
package learning.logging;


import lab.error.logging.ErrorLogger;
import lab.error.logging.ErrorStatus;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class LogTester {

  private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory().getLogger("LogTester");

  @Test
  public void appenderPOC() {
    log.error("My custom appender POC");
  }
}
```

Console output:

```
layout loaded in appender from constructor: ---WCustomAppender--- %m %n
message: My custom appender POC
message (formatted): My custom appender POC
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have found the issue:

I spotted that the `AbstractAppender` has a method called `toSerializable` that checks if there is a layout present (which in my case it is), then it applies it to the `LogEvent`. So in my `WCustomAppender` I switched out the `getLogEvents` to return a list of `Serializable` instead to verify in testing.

```java
    /**
     * Serializes the given event using the appender's layout if present.
     *
     * @param event
     *            the event to serialize.
     * @return the serialized event or null if no layout is present.
     */
    protected Serializable toSerializable(final LogEvent event) {
        return layout != null ? layout.toSerializable(event) : null;
    }
```

Console output:

```
message: ---WCustomAppender--- My custom appender POC
```